# find the Errors for $ \ n=2 \ $ and $ \ n=20 \ $

Tags: numerical-methods

Let $ \ I=\large \int_a^b f(x) dx=7.621372 \ $ and let the trapezoidal approximation for $ \ n=2 \ $ is given by $ I_T=\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx 7.362011 \ $ . Then find the Errors for $ \ n=2 \ $ and $ \ n=20 \ $

**Answer:**

$n $ = number of sub-intervals

For $ n=2 \ $ the Error is given by $ E=|I-I_T|=|7.621372-7.362011|=0.259361 \ $

**But how to find the Error for $ \ n=20 \ $ ?**

**Help me out**

Comment: What are a, b, and n? What does each mean?

Comment: $ n $ is the number  of sub-intervals  and $ [a,b] $ is the interval of integration.

Comment: What is the function $f$?

Comment: That is all given in the question. Only the exact integral value is given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is $O(h^2)=O(n^{-2})$, your best guess is to divide by $10^2=100$ to get a probable error for $n=20$ of $0.0026$.